# Error trying to load data from Excel

Tags: ssis, null, decimal

I'm in SSIS and trying to populate a table in my database  with results on a formatted Spreadsheet. I'm using the SQL command within the Excel source editor and bring through data

[image]

I can see that some values within the rates colunms are blank. The error im geeting is .

```
 An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
```

This there an connection?

Comment: Is the error on your source or destination? If its on source try to make a columns nvarchar

Comment: Look to be my destination.

Comment: So do you have specific datatypes on your destination? Try to set them all to match your source or make them all nvarchar. Than you can handle datatypes afterwards.

Comment: All fields in my SQL Table are Nvarchar. is it the OLE DB destination i need to change my data types?

Comment: Yes if they are not nvarchar i would try that.

Comment: try to use table or view access mode also instead of sql command in your excel source. And then in your destination let it create a new table by selecting new. Then it automactilly detects column datatypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here works for me, so you can try somethin similar:

All column datatypes is of nvarchar(255) except sc which is a float(but you can change this to nvarchar if you wish)

Try to get this working first. If you then get data loaded, you can always change datatypes as you go further or make a new dataflow where you handle your datatypes.

**Excel Sheet:**

[image]

**Package start:**
[image]

**Excel source Editor**
[image]

**Excel Source Columns**
[image]

**Destination connection and create new table**
[image]

**Destination mappings**
[image]

**SQL Table Result**
[image]

Comment: I have managed to get the data loaded , is there away that i can insert into an existing table ?